# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime works for US users but not for users in Ireland

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timezone

I have an app in which a user can query a database to look for results of a test.  When they double click on one of the results it opens another form to show the data.  I developed this in Arizona and the database test times show Arizona time for users in both Arizona and Ireland. Part of the second form that opens needs to access a log file and the problem with the Irish log files is that the time listed in the filename is in GMT not AZ time.

For example, the database shows the test time as 12/05/2018 08:31 AM but the log file name for an Irish test is 12/05/2018 15:31.  To handles this when developing I added a correction from the test time to the log file time as follows:

```
 var IRTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
 var IRMetroDateCor = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(testtime, IRTimeZone)
```

This successfully works when I run the app - it finds the log file with no problem.  I just deployed this to Ireland for them to test and through some troubleshooting we found that the ConvertTime line is not doing anything.  The time remains 12/05/2018 8:31AM.

Any ideas on why this would work here but not there?  Other ways to handle this so it works for both sites?

Comment: The culture is different due to PC settings.   Ireland uses dd/MM/yyyy while US uses MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem here though.  After the above I take the time and convert to string with format "yyyMMddHHmmss" as this is actually how the log file name starts.  The problem is that it converts to 20181205153131 for me after this while it stays at 20181205083131 for them.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference.  The PC stores a DateTime as a number in UTC time.  The when the datetime is input/output to a string the conversion ToString() is done using the timezone settings of the PC.  So the conversion from Ireland Time to MST (Mountain Standard Time) is 7 hours.  If you display the time to include the timezone value you would see the difference.

Comment: Time (and time zones) are complicated.  How do you persist the time, in UTC, or as some local time.  Your phrase _"database test times show"_ makes me think that you have Arizona time in your database.  If you want to get this to work, you are going to really want to persist time as UTC time, and convert it from/local time for every user.  If you have AZ time in the db, then you will need to convert from that time to the user's local time for display (and that's tricky to get consistently right).

Comment: Is `testtime`, a `DateTime` or a `DateTimeOffset`? Please start from a string and show how you create that variable.  For a `DateTime`, this matters greatly, due to how `ConvertTime` behaves differently with regard to the `Kind` property of a `DateTime`, and how `Kind` is set when you first create the value.  For a `DateTimeOffset`, the offset will also affect the conversion.

Comment: Also, make sure you recognize that `"GMT Standard Time"` is the correct time zone id for Ireland, but it is not GMT year round.  It uses GMT (UTC+0) in the winter and IST (UTC+1) in the summer.  If your timestamps are UTC year round, then you'll need to use the id `"UTC"`, or `TimeZoneInfo.Utc`, where appropriate.

Comment: `testtime` is taken from the datagridview cell like this: `testtime = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridViewTestList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value);`

Comment: And yes, the database uses Arizona time.  Also, thanks for the tip on GMT in Ireland.

Answer (score 0):

Going from the information you provided in the question's comments:

> `testtime` is taken from the datagridview cell like this:
>
> ```
> testtime = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridViewTestList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value);
> ```

The `Value` property of a `DataGridViewCell` is of type `object`, which means it can be anything.  In this case it's likely either a `string` in a particular format, or it's already a `DateTime`.  That depends largely on how you populated the `DataGridView` in the first place.

- If the cell value is already a `DateTime`, then `Convert.ToDateTime` is just passing it through untouched.  You might as well just cast it with `(DateTime) theValue` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime(theValue)`.  You would get the same results.

  - The resulting value's `.Kind` property will be identical to the input value's.  It might be any of `DateTimeKind.Utc`, `DateTimeKind.Local`, or `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.
- If the cell values is a `string`, then `Convert.ToDateTime` is *parsing* the string, using the current culture.  It is equivalent to calling `DateTime.Parse(theValue)`, except that you get none of the extra parameters for controlling the parsing.

  - The resulting value's `.Kind` property will be `DateTimeKind.Local` if there is any time zone information in the input string, or `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` if there is not.  It cannot be `DateTimeKind.Utc`, coming out of `Convert.ToDateTime`.

As you can see, depending on how you obtain the `DateTime` value, its `.Kind` property can vary.  This matters because that controls the behavior of `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`, as described [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTime_System_DateTime_System_TimeZoneInfo_) (scroll to the "Remarks" section).

Importantly, note that if the `Kind` is `Unspecified`, then it is treated the same as if it is `Local`.  So what is likely happening in your case is that the conversion is always going from local time (whatever that might be) to Irish time.   So for Irish users, it doesn't appear to change at all.

If the intent is to go from Arizona time to Irish time *always*, then you need to specify both time zones, and you need to make sure the input `Kind` is always `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

```
// This is needed if the Kind isn't already Unspecified
DateTime timeInArizona = DateTimeKind.SpecifyKind(testtime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

// Get the from and to time zone  (yes, the IDs have weird naming conventions)
TimeZoneInfo arizonaTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo irelandTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");

// Do the conversion, specifying both time zones
DateTime timeInIreland = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(timeInArizona, arizonaTimeZone, irelandTimeZone);
```